# Using jq how to add the key to the existing JSON data structure

Tags: json, jq

Hello and thanks in advance,

So I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "key1" : { 
     "someKey": "someValue"
  },
  "key2" : { 
     "someKey": "someValue"
  }
}
```

and the output that I'm looking for is:

```
[
  { 
     "someKey": "someValue",
     "$key" : "key1"
  },
  { 
     "someKey": "someValue",
     "$key" : "key2"
  }
]
```

So basically I need to append the 'key' to the value as a separate property in the value of that key's object using jq.

I already figured out how to convert the values into an array, but I cannot figure out how to add the "$key" to the object.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: Jordan, I'm using jq https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ on the terminal

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution using the following command:

```
[ to_entries[] | {"$key": .key} * .value ]
```

How this works?

The `to_entries[]` outputs

```
{
 "key": "key1",
  "value": {
    "someKey": "someValue"
  }
}
{
  "key": "key2",
  "value": {
    "someKey": "someValue"
  }
}
```

Then it pipes this output using '|', after piping it creates an object

```
{"$key": .key}
```

Then, using the `*` operator, it merges this new object with the object located at the `.value` key from each object from the `to_entries[]` output.

The outermost wrapping with `[]` just creates an array from the stream.

Comment: Instead of `[.[] | f]`, one can do `map(f)`: `to_entries | map({"$key": .key} + .value)`